# Поиск значений и ключей по словарю в питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть кол-во словарей выдаваемых в цикле for:

```
{'LastImportUpdateTS': '2022-08-02T06:46:20.6511824Z', 'Value': 'olaesbulcu', 'PendingInboundValue': 'olaesbulcu', 'PendingExportValue': None, 'LastOutboundUpdateTs': None, 'IACDeletedTS': None, 'AttributeName': 'exportSourceAnchor'},
{'LastImportUpdateTS': '2022-08-02T06:46:20.6511824Z', 'Value': 'olaesbulcu1', 'PendingInboundValue': 'olaesbulcu1', 'PendingExportValue': None, 'LastOutboundUpdateTs': None, 'IACDeletedTS': None, 'AttributeName': 'AlternateEmailAddress'}
```

У каждого из них есть ключ 'AttributeName' и если значение ключа равно 'exportSourceAnchor' как у первого, то необходимо вывести 'Value' в этом же словаре, но у меня не выходит. Подскажите как это правильно сделать.

Вот что я попробовал:

```
 for k, v in y.items():
            if v == 'exportSourceAnchor':
                
                print(k, v)
```

но это не то потому что если найдет 'exportSourceAnchor' то выведет его ключ 'AttributeName'. А мне нужно прописать условие так чтобы если значение
'AttributeName' == 'exportSourceAnchor' то вывести 'Value': 'olaesbulcu' ---- значение моэет отличаться. Помогите плиз. 2 часа мучаюсь!!

Comment: если не перестанете искажать вопросы - получите временный бан учетной записи, оно вам надо?

Comment: Вы ничего в итоге так не добъетесь. Вас просто заблокируют, а вопросы вернут в нормальное состояние.

Comment: Зачем вы их отвкатываете? Написано удалено пользователем

Answer (score 5):

ну выводите явно этот ключ если найдет совпадение

```
my_lst = [
    {'LastImportUpdateTS': '2022-08-02T06:46:20.6511824Z', 'Value': 'olaesbulcu', 'PendingInboundValue': 'olaesbulcu', 'PendingExportValue': None, 'LastOutboundUpdateTs': None, 'IACDeletedTS': None, 'AttributeName': 'exportSourceAnchor'},
    {'LastImportUpdateTS': '2022-08-02T06:46:20.6511824Z', 'Value': 'olaesbulcu1', 'PendingInboundValue': 'olaesbulcu1', 'PendingExportValue': None, 'LastOutboundUpdateTs': None, 'IACDeletedTS': None, 'AttributeName': 'AlternateEmailAddress'}
]
for el in my_lst:
    for k, v in el.items():
        if v == 'exportSourceAnchor':
            print(el['Value'])
```

Comment: Да спасибо. Все очень просто оказалось)

Comment: @ДианаТихонова даже можно убрать `k`, т.к. ключи не используются и вместо `items` исgользовать метода  `values()`